# Is it possible to make mat-button-toggle-group to be responsive?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular6

`mat-button-toggle-group` does not wrap toggle buttons on small screens. Is it possible to force `mat-button-toggle-group` to be responsive?

**Code below is not responsive somehow:**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-9">
      <mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
        <mat-button-toggle value="bold" buttonToggleGroup="fontStyle">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="italic" buttonToggleGroup="fontStyle">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="underline" buttonToggleGroup="fontStyle">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="bold" buttonToggleGroup="fontStyle">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="italic" buttonToggleGroup="fontStyle">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="underline" buttonToggleGroup="fontStyle">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="bold" buttonToggleGroup="fontStyle">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="italic" buttonToggleGroup="fontStyle">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="underline" buttonToggleGroup="fontStyle">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
      </mat-button-toggle-group>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use @angular/flex-layout to watch to mediaquery, and depending on the size of the window, show the full  or show a  and a button and a mat-menu with the options.

here is an example : https://angular-rb5vmu.stackblitz.io look at "angular material responsive mat-button-toggle-group" and try it adjusting thew browser window width

Comment: thank you for the trick,  i played with orientation and mediaquery. I wanted 2x4, 3x3, 4x2 wrapped buttons depending on screen size. But it looks like `mat-button-toggle-group` is not intended for mobile use.

Comment: I couldn't make it responsive neither, so I just used a button and a menu in small screens.

Comment: setting vertical="boolean_condition" in <mat-button-toggle-group> will do the work.. Is there any way to set 'boolean_condition' to true for flex layout 'lt-sm' (small screen size) ?

Comment: To add to @shaheershukur's comment:

In your HTML:

`<mat-button-toggle-group [vertical]="isVertical"...>`

`...`

`<mat-button-toggle-group>`

In your TS:

`...`

`public get isVertical: boolean {`
`return true;`
`}`

`...`